# Unable to manipulate arrays using "unset"

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array of docker containers, arr=(testfoler1 testfoler2 testfoler3 testfoler1)

i know testfoler1 has file notify.txt at location /tmp/, i.e. /tmp/notify.txt.
testfoler2 and testfoler3, are empty.

Now my requirement is once this file is found i will stop the container and will remove that container from arr.

So the flow should  be like this.

step 1: /tmp/notify.txt is found in testfoler1 and the new array will be,
    arr=(testfoler2 testfoler3 testfoler1)

step 2: it will search for testfolder2 and testfolder3, but as no file is there no action is performed.

step 3: as it reaches to testfoler1 which is at the 2nd index, it will find the notify.txt file and it should remove it from array.

And my last expected array would be (testfoler2 testfoler3) and the loop should keep on running until the file is found or i stop the script.

> My script runs successfully til it iterate to (testfoler1 testfoler2
>   testfoler3). Issue start coming when my array becomes (testfoler2
>   testfoler3 testfoler1). Here it work fine for testfolder2 and
>   testfolder3 as file is not found but when it reaches to testfolder1,
>   instead of removing the testfolder1, it removes testfolder2 and array becomes 
>   (testfoler3 testfoler1) instead of (testfoler2 testfoler3) And then
>   keep iterating and then it removes testfolder3 and then
>   testfoler1.However it should have deleted testfolder1 because it had
>   the file and should have kept running for testfolder2 and testfolder3.

Please refer the code i have tried with:

```
FILE=/tmp/notify.txt

arr=(testfoler1 testfoler2 testfoler3 testfoler1)

sizeOfArray="${#arr[@]}"
index=0

while [ ! $sizeOfArray -eq 0 ]

do
    sizeOfArray="${#arr[@]}"
    test=`sudo docker container diff ${arr[index]}|grep $FILE|wc -l`
     if [ $test = 1 ]; then
      echo "notify.txt is found in container ${arr[index]}"  
            ##Get array length
            sizeOfArray="${#arr[@]}"
            sudo docker stop ${arr[index]}
            sudo docker container ls -a|grep ${arr[index]}

            ###################Issue seems to be here
            unset arr[${arr[index]}]
            arr=( "${arr[@]}" ) 
            ##################Need some help on code above          
            echo "When file is FOUND, name of all array elements ${arr[*]}"
            echo "Size of array after deletion *********** "${#arr[@]}""

            sizeOfArray="${#arr[@]}"
            index=$((index + 1))
            if [ $index -gt $sizeOfArray ] ; then
            index=0 
            fi
            continue
    else
        echo "notify file is not created in ${arr[index]}"
            echo "When file is NOT found, name of all array elements ${arr[*]}"
        index=$((index + 1))
        if [ $index -ge $sizeOfArray ]; then
        echo "Index value is greater/equal size of suites"
        index=0 
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: [tag:sh] doesn't have arrays, so I went out on a limb and assumed that you are actually using [tag:bash]. If that's not the case, please change the tag to the actual shell you're using.

Comment: As an aside, anything that looks like `hits=$(command | grep something | wc -l); if [ $hits -gt 0 ]` is much better written `if command | grep -q something`

Answer (score 1):

This does not delete element `index` of `arr`:

```
unset arr[${arr[index]}]
```

If that's what you intended to do, you should use:

```
unset arr[index]
```